# Resilience4j bulkhead issue with @bulkhead in springboot

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, design-patterns, annotations

I am implementing bulkhead pattern in springboot using @bulkhead annotation. I have this configuration
resilience4j.bulkhead:
instances:
performanceService:
maxConcurrentCalls: 2
maxWaitDuration: 1ms

on my service method I have
@Bulkhead(name = "performanceService", fallbackMethod = "getDefaultPerformanceData")

However it is not working. When I call performance endpoint I am directly getting the getDefaultPerformanceData().

is there something I am doing wrong.